# NSPoint in NSBezierPath

Tags: point, nsbezierpath

I was wondering if there is any way to find out if an NSPoint is inside an NSBezierPath. Like:

```
NSPointInRect(aPoint,aRect)
```

But with a BezierPath.

Thanks in advance, Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. See this method:

```
containsPoint:
```

Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the receiver contains the specified point.

```
- (BOOL)containsPoint:(NSPoint)aPoint
```

Parameters
aPoint
The point to test against the path, specified in the path object's coordinate system.